# multiple uitextview.becomeFirstResponder not working when recalling

Tags: swift, uitextfield, getter-setter, becomefirstresponder

I am trying to make a collection view with full view sized cells, that has text fields on every cell (view). This will be the registration pages for my app. Every time I flip the cell/page (which is a full view), I want the textview in the cell to become active, keyboard to pop-up and the text typed to write into the cell's textview.
Everything works fine until the I go back on a previous page, then the text view in the cell does not become active any longer. This is because my .becomeFirstResponder() returns false though although I am in the correct case.

this is my code

```
var currentPage: Int {
        set(newValue){
        if newValue <= 0 {curPg = 0}
        else if newValue >= book.count  {curPg = book.count - 1}
        else {curPg = newValue}

        switch newValue {
        case 0:
            refreshButtonSettings()

            nextButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(nextPage), for: .touchUpInside)

            backButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(cancel), for: .touchUpInside)
            backButton.setTitle("Cancel", for: .normal)

            personName.becomeFirstResponder()
            personName.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

        case 1:
            defaultButtonSettings()
            birthDate.becomeFirstResponder()

        case 2:
            defaultButtonSettings()

            nextButton.isEnabled = false
            nextButton.alpha = 0.5

            userName.becomeFirstResponder()

        case 3:
            defaultButtonSettings()

            passWord.becomeFirstResponder()

        case 4:
            defaultButtonSettings()
            phoneNumber.becomeFirstResponder()

        case book.count-1:
            refreshButtonSettings()

            email.becomeFirstResponder()

            backButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(previousPage), for: .touchUpInside)
            backButton.setTitle("< ", for: .normal)

            nextButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(sendEmailVerification), for: .touchUpInside)

        default:
            return
        }
        print(personName.isFirstResponder)
        print(birthDate.isFirstResponder)
        print(userName.isFirstResponder)
        print(passWord.isFirstResponder)
        print(phoneNumber.isFirstResponder)
        print(email.isFirstResponder)

    }
    get {
        return curPg
    }
}


func defaultButtonSettings(){
    refreshButtonSettings()

    nextButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(nextPage), for: .touchUpInside)

    backButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(previousPage), for: .touchUpInside)
    backButton.setTitle("< ", for: .normal)
}


func refreshButtonSettings(){
    nextButton.removeTarget(nil, action: nil, for: .allEvents)
    backButton.removeTarget(nil, action: nil, for: .allEvents)

    nextButton.isEnabled = true
    nextButton.alpha = 1
}
```

Comment: Is your `becomeFirstResponder` is returning false for all the textviews or for any particular?

Comment: It’s returning true for one at a time like it needs to as I move through pages. However, whenever I change direction (say I’m going through pages from left to right, then decide to go back from right to left) it returns false for all. Which makes no sense to me.

Comment: When you are moving from right to left, to which case it is going? Can you please check what is the `newValue`?

Comment: newValue will be ex 0,1,2,4,3,2 -> no overlaps whatsoever so no 0,1,3,4,4,3,2. That’s why it’s so strange